# Relating Fourier and power-law descriptions of noise

Tags: power-spectral-density, time-series, power-law

I'm trying to understand [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.8319.pdf) PDF, which is in English but has Polish authors, so there may be translation issues confusing me. The subject is the frequencies of sentence lengths in novels.

Eq. (1), $S(f)=\left|\sum_{j=1}^{j_\max}l(j)e^{-2\pi ifj}\right|^2$, claims to present a power spectrum "of the series $l(j)$ representing lengths of the consecutive sentences $j$". It is then claimed empirical $S$-against-$f$ plots exhibit Eq. (7), $S(f)=1/f^\beta$.

I expect that might be meant to be a proportionality relation, but let's put that aside for the moment. To my mind, these equations are incompatible, because (1) implies $S(f+1)=S(f)$, with a finite peak in $S$ at integer $f$, including $f=0$, by the triangle inequality in $\Bbb C$. By contrast, a $1/f^\beta$ law is monotonic decreasing on $f\ge0$, with a divergence at $f=0$.

Figure 1 suggests values of $f$ from about $10^{-3}$ to $10^{-1}$ are considered, which on log-log axes allows one to make a power-law approximation, but I don't see the merit in that. But supposing this is a standard procedure, how would I estimate $\beta$ for $l$ from my own time series? Is there, for example, a computationally cheap library function to estimate $\beta$?

Comment: Would you be able to expand on why you think $S(f+1) = S(f)$?

Comment: @StephenJackson Because $e^{-2\pi i(f+1)j}=e^{-2\pi ifj}e^{-2\pi ij}$, the last factor being $1$ because $j\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @StephenJackson Wait: is the value of $j_\max$ dependent on $f$?

Comment: No I don't think so, I think $j_{\text{max}}$ is just the number of sentences, and I also cant fault your logic here, usually I would expect that (1) would be written as $$S(f) = |\sum_{j=1}^{j_{\text{max}}}l(j)e^{-2\pi i f \frac{j}{j_{\text{max}}}}|^2$$ so usually $S(f+1) \neq S(f)$ but this doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: @StephenJackson In which case $S(f+j_\max)=S(f)$.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I don't think you can recover frequencies above your maximum number of samples, for example you can't find 10 sentences with length 3 words from a sample of 5 sentences. It's deliberately restricted to $j_{\text{max}}$ exactly so that the above property is satisfied, because you are trying to represent the function as a linear combination of periodic basis functions, so it has to be periodic itself.